# Scrapy splash not load content

Tags: web-scraping, printing, scrapy, void, scrapy-splash

I started using selenium a few months ago, then scrapy. Learning tutorials from Udemy, youtube, and stackoverflow questions, all the scrapes were successful, until I started working with this page , response.css or response.xpath didn't work, so I went to scrapy-splash. I installed docker, and did many tests, and I had successful responses. I have tried all the solutions I have found and it doesn't work, it doesn't even print.I tried python 3.8 and 2.7 with scrapy-splash.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

LUA_SCRIPT = """
function main(splash)
    splash.private_mode_enabled = false
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:wait(2)
    html = splash:html()
    splash.private_mode_enabled = true
    return html
end
"""

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    start_urls = ["url"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args={
                                    'wait': 1,
                                    "lua_source":LUA_SCRIPT})

    def parse(self, response):
        print ('Result:')
        print(".breadcrumbs-link = %s" % (response.css('body').extract())) # OUTPUT: [...HTML ELEMENTS...]
        print(".breadcrumbs-link = %s" % (response.xpath("//td'][1]").extract()))
```

```
(Face python 3.8) F:\Selenium\>scrapy crawl quotes
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: scrapysplash)
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.0 (tags/v
3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-7
-SP0
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'scrapysplash',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapysplash.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapysplash.spiders']}
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: f075a705cb8e0509
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-31 04:31:00 [py.warnings] WARNING: d:\selenium\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy_splash\request.py:41: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated fu
nction to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
  url = to_native_str(url)

2020-07-31 04:31:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://url/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-07-31 04:31:01 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET url>
2020-07-31 04:31:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-07-31 04:31:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 223,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 370,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.355421,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 31, 8, 31, 1, 228466),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/forbidden': 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 31, 8, 31, 0, 873045)}
2020-07-31 04:31:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Are you getting any response back ? As in response.text in your parse function. Also you need to include ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False in your settings.py.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have an answer, but I don't bring anything.
").extract_first()))            None 
/text()").extract_first()))     None
/text()").extract()))           []
/text()").getall()))            []
").getall()))                   []

Comment: I got response with absolute xpath, but with that I can't interact with the table.

Comment: You need to figure out your XPATH selectors then. As a tip don't mix extract and get. Get is preferred for grabbing one value, getall() for if the XPATH selector has mulitple values. The reason is that with extract() you don't know whether you'll get a list or just a string value.

Comment: Have you managed to get the correct response ?

Comment: yes, it helped me a lot